# How to bind a changing Long number to a Label in javafx so that the label constantly updates

Tags: javafx

I can bind the changing number once at the start but it won't update for the rest of the runtime.

I've tried adding a listener but didn't work correctly. There probably is a really simple solution but I can't seem to find it.

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Mainclass extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox stackPane = new VBox();
        Label label = new Label();



//the stuff that actually matters

        LongProperty longProperty = new SimpleLongProperty();
        longProperty.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        label.textProperty().bind(longProperty.asString());




        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see, in the code you posted, where you are changing the value of `longProperty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label.textProperty().bind(longProperty.asString());
```

This sets the binding correctly. when ever "longProperty" changes, the text of "label" will change to the same value. 
You don't see anything changing in your example because longProperty is not changing

```
longProperty.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This is a simple setter which sets the value of "longProperty" to the currentTimeMillis value at that time but it will stay at that value. It is not a binding!

If you really want to have a label display the currentTimeMillis value, you could do something like this.

```
class CurrentTimeMillisService extends ScheduledService<Void>
{
    private final LongProperty longProperty;

    public CurrentTimeMillisService( LongProperty longProperty )
    {
        this.longProperty = longProperty;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask()
    {
        return new Task<>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception
            {
                Platform.runLater( () -> longProperty.set( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This creates a service that updates a longProperty with the value from System.currentTimesMillis().

```
//the stuff that actually matters
LongProperty longProperty = new SimpleLongProperty();
CurrentTimeMillisService timeService = new CurrentTimeMillisService( longProperty );
timeService.setPeriod( Duration.seconds( 1 ) );
timeService.start();

label.textProperty().bind( longProperty.asString() );
```

This binds your "longProperty" to the service and runs the service once a second.

There maybe easier ways to do this but that's the first i came up with.

Comment: omg it works. thanks very much. been stuck on this for too long that im willing to admit. Also learned alot. TYVM